# Diffusion from bulk to cylinder wall

Tags: diffusion, absorption

If D is the diffusion constant of particles, C is concentration, R is the radius, diffusion to disk-like adsorber is 4DRC, and hemisphere is 2piDRC. So what is the diffusion equation to a cylinder lateral area (cylinder wall)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is $4DRC$ and $2\pi DRC$? I'd like to answer your question but it isn't very clear...

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I'm trying to understand particle adsorption from infinite bulk to a cylinder. Every particle reaching the surface of the cylinder is gobbled up. Thus, the concentration at the cylinder surface is 0. The bulk concentration is C. I know that the top and bottom surfaces of the cylinder can be considered as a disk-shaped adsorber of radius R. The diffusion current I=4DRC (Ref: Random walks in biology, page 28). But what would be the diffusion current to the cylinder wall? I

Comment: Look at the answer please. Do you want me to carry on?

Answer (score 0):

> Every particle reaching the surface of the cylinder is gobbled up.
> Thus, the concentration at the cylinder surface is 0.

No, that's impossible because it would create a discontinuity at the boundary $R=r$. The actual concentration at that boundary is in fact:

$$C(t,R)=C_0$$

where $C_0$ is the concentration at the bulk medium. So the condition above gives us a boundary condition.

Assume the cylinder is much longer than its radius ($L \gg R$), so we can treat it as an infinitely long cylinder. The concentration inside the cylinder ($\in [0,R]$) is then invariant to $z$ (the length-wise coordinate)

The 'go to' equation here is [Fick's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick%27s_second_law), here in cylindrical coordinates and using PDE short hand:

$$C_t=D\left(\frac{1}{r} C_r\left(r C_r\right)\right)\tag{1}$$

(Note that there's also no dependence on $\varphi$, due to symmetry)

Develop $(1)$ to get:

$$\frac1D C_t=\frac{C_r}{r}+C_{rr}$$

So we're looking for a function $C(t,r)$ that satisfies $(2)$, as well as $(1)$.

We also need an initial condition:

$$C(0,r)=f(r)\text{ for } r \in [0,R]$$

---

**Solution to the PDE with Separation of Variables**:

Assume that:

$$C(t,r)=\Theta(t)R(r)$$

Insert in the PDE and Rework:
$$\frac1D \Theta' R=\frac1r \Theta R'+\Theta R''$$
$$\frac1D \frac{\Theta'}{\Theta}=\frac1r \frac{R'}{R}+\frac{R''}{R}=-m^2$$
Which gives us two ODEs:
$$\frac1D \frac{\Theta'}{\Theta}=-m^2$$

where $-m^2$ is a separation constant,

and:
$$\frac1r \frac{R'}{R}+\frac{R''}{R}=-m^2$$
$$rR''+R'+m^2R=0$$
Which has the standard solution:
$$R_m(r)=c_1J_0(2m\sqrt{r})+c_2Y_0(2m\sqrt{r})$$

Where $J_0$ and $Y_0$ are the Bessel functions. Because for $r \to 0$, then $Y_0(0) \to \infty$, thus must mean:
$$c_2=0$$
Using our boundary condition:
$$C_0=c_1J_0(2m\sqrt{R })$$
So we have a problem because we don't have the value of $c_1$.

To solve it we make a *substitution*:
$$u(t,r)=C(t,r)-C_0$$
Because all the drivatives $u_t=C_t, u_{rr}=C_{rr}$ are invariant, the solution of the PDE remains the same, but the BC has now become homogeneous:
$$0=c_1J_0(2m\sqrt{R })$$
Thus:
$$\Rightarrow 0=J_0(2m\sqrt{R })$$
$$2m_i\sqrt{R }=z_i$$
Where the $z_i$ are the roots of $J_0$:

[image: Bessel roots]

Thus the values of the $m_i$ are now known as:

$$m_i=\frac{z_i}{2\sqrt{R}}$$
The time-ODE solves very easily to:
$$\Theta_i(t)=\exp{\left(-m_i^2Dt\right)}$$
The eigenfunctions of $R_i(r)$ are:
$$R_i(r)=c_1J_0(2m_i\sqrt{r}))$$
So:
$$u_i(t,r)=b_i\exp{\left(-m_i^2Dt\right)}J_0(2m_i\sqrt{r}))$$
We'll deal with the coefficients $b_i$ below. Due to Superposition:
$$u(t,r)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i\exp{\left(-m_i^2Dt\right)}J_0(2m_i\sqrt{r}))$$
Now remember that for $t=0 \Rightarrow u(0,r)$:
$$u(0,r)=f(r)-C_0$$
So:
$$f(r)-C_0=\sum_{i=1}^\infty b_iJ_0(2m_i\sqrt{r}))$$
Using the Fourier series we find:
$$b_i=\frac2R\int_0^R\mathrm{d}r\left[\left(f(r)-C_0)\right)J_0(2m_i\sqrt{r}))\right]$$
And of course:
$$C(t,r)=u(t,r)+C_0$$

---

The result may seem a little daunting due to two factors:

- the infinite series
- the use of the Bessel function $J_0$

Yopu can approximate $C(t,r)$ by using only the first 2 or 3 terms of the series because the exponential term decays very quickly with increasing $z_i^2$.

The Bessel function (First kind) $J_0$ is a quasi-cosine. Replace that factor with suitable cosine function, as an approximation. I've done this before with good results in more complex problems.

To do so, replace the Bessel function with:

$$\cos\left(2m_i\sqrt{r}\right)$$

Then consider the boundary condition:

$$0=\cos\left(2m_i\sqrt{r}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow 2m_i\sqrt{r}=\frac{i\pi}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow=m_i =\frac{i\pi}{4\sqrt{r}}\text{ for }i=1,2,3,...$$

You will also have to recalculate the $b_i$.

Comment: Hi Gert, thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Regarding the discontinuity of concentration at boundary, I was actually referring to the "Diffusion to Capture" model in which the a perfectly absorbing boundary is assumed (e.g. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biological_Chemistry/Concepts_in_Biophysical_Chemistry_(Tokmakoff)/03%3A_Diffusion/10%3A_Diffusion/10.03%3A_Steady-State_Solutions)

Comment: That's quite interesting and you have basically a complete solution in that text. libretexts is very dependable.

Comment: Hi Gert, I still need some help. Based on the spherical absorbing solution in that text, how do I derive for cylinder wall absorbing boundary?

Comment: Did you mean *cylinder wall absorbing boundary condition*?

Comment: That BC is Eq. 10.3.4., i.e. $\frac{\partial C}{\partial r} \right|_{r=a} = - \frac{DC_0}{a}$

Comment: But Eq. 10.3.4 is only derived for spherical surface BC, not cylinder wall absorbing boundary condition.

Comment: No, it's not. It's valid for ANY coordinate system. It's simply a general condition for this 'Diffusion to Capture' thingy.

Comment: Here's a suggestion. Why not ask a fresh question, well posed and clear about your problem. Ping me here so I know where it is. Me and others (?) will then try to answer.

Comment: Hi Gert, here is my fresh question. Hope it's clear this time. Thanks a lot! https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/677961/318837

Comment: Thanks. Will see to it later on today.