# Diffusion to capture on the surface of a cylinder wall

Tags: collision, diffusion

[image]

Hi all, is it correct to use equation 10.3.4 on the above textbook for the flux of particles onto a surface of the cylinder wall (radius a, length L)? If yes, then the rate of collisions of particles to the wall will be the equation below? Thanks!
$$ j=JA=(\frac{DC_0}{a})*2{\pi}*a*L=2{\pi}DLC_0 $$

Answer (score 0):

For the cylindrical geometry we get (steady state):
$$\frac{1}{r} C_r\left(r C_r\right)=0$$
For $r\neq 0$ and assume $L\gg a$ (cylinder length), so we can neglect diffusion on the end-caps:
$$C_r+rC_{rr}=0$$
Solution:
$$C(r)=c_1\ln r+c_2$$
First boundary condition:
$$C(a)=0$$
$$0=c_1\ln a+c_2$$
Second boundary condition:
$$J(a) = -D \left. \dfrac{\partial C}{\partial r} \right|_{r=a} = - \dfrac{DC_0}{a}$$
$$-Dc_1\frac{1}{a}=- \dfrac{DC_0}{a}$$
$$\Rightarrow c_1=C_0$$
$$\Rightarrow c_2=-c_1\ln a$$
$$C(r)=C_0\ln r-C_0\ln a=C_0\ln \frac{r}{a}$$
So that:

$$\boxed{j=JA=2 \pi D La}$$

Comment: Please accept this answer if you think it's correct.

Comment: Hi @Gert, I followed your logic, but arrived at a different result. Please see the new image posted above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is there a problem with the 2nd boundary condition?

Comment: It would be helpful to type out the answer here instead of posting a picture, particularly for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Your answer appears to be correct. I will scrutinise it more tomorrow. Ta.

Comment: If my answer is correct, isn't it quite interesting that the rate of particle adsorption at a cylindrical wall only depends on the length, not the radius?